# Make part of UIImageView transparent

Tags: iphone

I have an two UIImageView that both have image & they are intersecting.
Can I make the intersection part transparent so that tha main background appear?

Answer (score 2):

To make the UIImageViews partially transparent:

```
[imageView1 setAlpha:0.5];
[imageView1 setOpaque:NO];

[imageView2 setAlpha:0.5];
[imageView2 setOpaque:NO];
```

(See [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView))

Or if the images themselves are static, you could open them in an image editor (Gimp, Photoshop), and change the intersecting region to have an alpha value of 0.

Comment: but this will make both imageviews partially transparent.I need the intersection region only!   & B.T.W the image are not static

Answer (score 0):

Create your images itself as transparent where they are intersecting......

Comment: Not what the question asked.